# How to properly insert time when user leaves( user_left and user_joined got the same value)

Tags: database, laravel

In this code, I would like to get time when the user joined and left and store it to DB. What happens it that I get the same value in both 'joined' and 'left' tables. How to fix it so it would store different values?

```
 Schema::create('user_info', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('ip');
        $table->string('joined');
        $table->string('left');
    });
```

in LoginController

```
public function logout() {
    $left = now();
    auth()->logout();
    session()->forget('name');
    session()->put('left',  $left);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

in Model

```
protected $fillable = ['ip','name', 'joined'];
const CREATED_AT = 'joined';
const UPDATED_AT = 'left';

public static function storeUser() { 
  UserInfo::create([
    'ip' => Request::ip(),
    'name' =>  Auth::user()->name, 
    'joined' => now(),   
 ]);  
}
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        $ip = Request::ip();
        $time = now(); 
        if (auth()->check() && !session()->has('name'))  { 
            UserInfo::storeUser();
            session()->put('name',$user->name);
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'joined' => $time,
            ];
        }
    });
```

This image illustates the behaviour after some changes you'll see below. It show that data with key 'left' for now goes not to the intended user but to the first user with this name.

[image: This strange behaviour]
The follow up of this question is here [How to override this code so that it insert data properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144926/how-to-override-this-code-so-that-it-insert-data-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AT` are timestamps that gets changed by the Eloquent model, whenever a model gets created it's also modified or `updated` from a non-existing to existing so this is why you get the same value

In the logout function, update the user's `left` column

```php
public function logout() {
    $user_id = auth()->id(); // Get authenticated user ID
    $user_info = App\UserInfo::find($user_id); // Get user info
    $user_info->left = now(); // Change here
    $user_info->save(); // Update here
    auth()->logout();
    session()->forget('name');
    session()->put('left',  $left);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

According to your table, there's no way to distinguish between users and their info since the name is not unique

Make a `user_id` based relationship

`User` model

```php
public function info()
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserInfo::class);
}
```

`UserInfo` model

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And in the `user_infos` migration

```php
Schema::create('user_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('ip');
    $table->dateTime('joined');
    $table->dateTime('left');
});
```

#### Cleaner Method

```php
public function logout() {
    $info = auth()->user()->info; // Get user info
    $info->left = now(); // Change here
    $info->save(); // Update here
    auth()->logout();
    session()->forget('name');
    session()->put('left',  $left);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've got an error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'left' in 'field list'

Comment: Edit your question and post your users table migration

Comment: I wrote `App\UserInfo` because I knew you will not import it, just copy-paste my code

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App\UserInfo' not found

Comment: Import the class `UserInfo` in the `LoginController` in the same way you imported it in `BroadcastServiceProvider`

Comment: Well, to get it work I should bring that UserInfo from another namespace. From App to be specific. In BroadcastServiceProvider  it was namespace App\Providers; In LoginController it's namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth; And when I try to use App\UserInfo it gives the error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\App\UserInfo' not found

Comment: Call it from the root then `\App\Userinfo`

Comment: This error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'left' in 'field list' remains the same.

Comment: You're still updating `left` on the user, call `$user_info->left = now();`

Comment: @ Caddy DZ This time I get the following error 'Trying to get property of non-object ' on this line           $user_info = \App\UserInfo::where('name', $user->name)->first();

Comment: It means the query returns no results and you're trying to access  `left` on it, make sure there's a `UserInfo` record with the name of the authenticated user

Comment: I've inspected data inserted in DB and I saw that this last user columns 'joined' and 'left' shows the same time but what changes is the 'left' time of this user from the very first record. Plus the 'Undefined variable: left' shows up when I logged out.

Comment: Am sorry but I can't help you like this, I'd need your entire application code to find what's wrong

Comment: I've  replaced this line  session()->put('left',  $left) with this session()->put('left', now()) and this error of undefined variable gone. Strange behaviour remains though.

Comment: What strange behavior?

Comment: Take a look above. I've added am image and a description of what happens. You see that early Kate got those data, not recent Kate.

Comment: aah, I thought that the name is unique, I updated my answer

Comment: Bravo! Just a few words I like to say.  I 've changed  $table->bigIncrements('id') with $table->increments('id')  cause it gave me server error. It was a pleasure, thanks!

Comment: Great! also check the cleaner method at the bottom since you now have a relationship

Comment: Please take a look. I opened another question as a follow up(with image). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144926/how-to-override-this-code-so-that-it-insert-data-properly