# How to override this code so that it insert data properly?

Tags: sql, database, laravel

This question is a follow-up of this one [How to properly insert time when user leaves( user_left and user_joined got the same value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134538/how-to-properly-insert-time-when-user-leaves-user-left-and-user-joined-got-the/58134683#58134683)

I get data when user logged in and store in in DB.

```
  Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        $ip = Request::ip();
        $time = now();  
        if (auth()->check() && !session()->has('name'))  { 
            UserInfo::storeUser();
            session()->put('name',$user->name);
            return [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'joined' => $time,                   
            ];
        }
    });
```

I get time when user logged out and also store in DB.

```
 public function logout() {
        $info = auth()->user()->info;
        $info->left = now(); 
        $info->save(); 
        auth()->logout();
        session()->forget('name');
        session()->put('left', now());
        return redirect('/');
      }
```

UserInfo model

```
public static function storeUser() { 
    UserInfo::create([
    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
    'ip' => Request::ip(),
    'name' =>  Auth::user()->name, 
    'joined' => now(),   
 ]);  
}
```

This is what I've got.
   [image]

The time when user left gets inserted not in the way I would like to. The first record with the name of the current user gets the time. I would like to see the LAST record of the current user receiving that data(when Syd 12 logged out Syd 10 received Syd's 12 'left' data. The same story goes with Kate.)

Comment: The first record didn't exist, you're not updating records, you're creating new ones all the time

Comment: @Caddy DZ   Take a look at id  10 and 12. You see that when Syd 12 logged out Syd 10 received Syd's 12 'left' data. The same story goes with Kate.

Comment: @Caddy DZ Under 'first records' I mean records 10 (for Syd) and 2 (for Kate). They are first because the most recent for those users.

Comment: Why are there many Kates and many Syds in the first place?

Comment: @Caddy DZ What do you mean? I store in DB data every time user logged in and logged out. Apparently, user's 'name' appears more than one time. This is the code from yesterday I used. I created I table with primary and foreign keys. What bothers me is that I thought that 'user_id' would increment, not 'id'.

Comment: @Caddy DZ Could you please have a look at the question? There's one thing I can't figure out how to do.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145745/how-to-get-user-by-his-user-id-in-eloquent-model. I tried to be more specific and the question is easy to understand.