# How to get current auto incremented value in this case?

Tags: database, laravel

As you'll see in the picture, data with time 'left' gets inserted in every field 'left' under the name of current user. This is because in function logout() I find the user by his id. But I would like to address the user by 'user_id' which is auto increment. How could I do it?
[image]

```
 public function logout() {
        $id = auth()->id();
        $info = \App\UserInfo::find($id);
        $info->left = now(); 
        $info->save(); 
        auth()->logout();
        session()->forget('name');
        session()->put('left',now());
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

If there were a way to get this $time value from UserInfo object we could update 'left' column.

```
$info = \App\UserInfo::where('id', $id)
    -> where('joined', $time)->first();
    ->update(['left' => now()]);
```

Anyway, this is the line to get it to work. Now it inserts without overriding other values.

```
 $user_info = \App\UserInfo::where('user_id', $id)->latest()->first();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `UserInfo` by the user_id

```php
$info = \App\UserInfo::where('user_id', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

Please note that your table will become huge if a lot of users login and logout, old data don't seem relevant if you want to implement the `last seen` feature of a messaging chat app

Comment: When I logged out, I see this error 'Creating default object from empty value'. But the record about current user appears in DB(with fields 'joined' and 'left' with the same value equal to 'joined').

Comment: Because there's no `UserInfo` record with the authenticated user id, I'll update my answer and tell me if you get 404

Comment: But there is a record about current user! (user_info) in DB. I guess that it just doesn't know about 'user_id'. But why?

Comment: Does it return 404 or not?

Comment: Then the record does not exist, the code works fine, your database is corrupted, run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still override all 'left' data for the current user.

Comment: You see the problem is that we look for $info = \App\UserInfo::where('user_id', $id)->first(); But we shoold look for the value under the key "user_id" ,and value $id is stored under the key 'id'.We get the value of  id by $id = auth()->id();But how can we get the autoincremented value under the key 'user_id'? If we get it, the code will work.

Comment: We're already doing exactly that, long story short, you only need 1 UserInfo per 1 user

Comment: I mean is there a way I can get address this value  under key 'user_id' ? (in the example it's numbers 7 and 8)

Comment: As I understand, UserModel just doesn't have this autoincremented data('user_id').

Comment: isn't UserModel the table in the image in your question?

Comment: Yes, it is. But in UserInfo create method I declared only  'id',  'ip' , 'name',   'joined'. 'user_id' was mentioned only in a schema as autoincremented. And now, I need to address its value.

Comment: If there was a way to get this $time value from UserInfo object we could update 'left' column. Please check the question.

Comment: Could you have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146967/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-this-variable. I would appreciate if you tell me if I am going the wrong way.